# Is it possible to add border-top, border-right,border-left properties individually under the decoration heading in grapesjs. similar to border radius

Tags: css, reactjs, grapesjs

Im not able to add left right bottom top border width using grapesjs style manager. [image][image]
Im using grapesjs-0.20.2

border-left ,border-right, border-top border-bottom [image]